# Find the singularities of $f(z) =\frac{1}{(2\sin z - 1)^2}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, singularity

Find the singularities of $f(z) =\frac{1}{(2\sin z - 1)^2}$.
I am just learning about singularities and I was wondering if someone could give me feedback on my work. So I think, for this function, that there are singularities at $z=\frac{\pi}{6}+2k\pi,\frac{5\pi}{6}+2k\pi$, would this be correct? Additionally, I am classifying them as essential and nonremovable. Is this also correct?

To determine that they were nonremovable, I tool the limit of the function approaching the singularities and found that they tended towards infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This $f$ has a singularity anywhere \begin{align*}
2 \sin z - 1 &= 0  \text{,}  \\
\sin z &= 1/2  \text{.}
\end{align*}
This has infinitely many solutions in the reals,
\begin{align*} 
z \in &\{ \arcsin(1/2) + 2 \pi k  : k \in \Bbb{Z} \} \cup  \\
\quad &\{\pi - \arcsin(1/2) + 2 \pi k : k \in  \Bbb{Z}\}  \\
 = & \{ \pi/6 + 2 \pi k  : k \in \Bbb{Z} \} \cup  \\
\quad &\{5\pi/6 + 2 \pi k : k \in  \Bbb{Z}\}  \text{.}
\end{align*}

It turns out these are the only two families of solutions, but you have done nothing to show that there are not more solutions.  To do so, start with, for $x,y\in\Bbb{R}$,
$$  \sin(x+\mathrm{i} \, y) = \sin(x) \cosh(y) + \mathrm{i} \cos(x) \sinh(y)  \text{.}  $$
Then talk about the zeroes of the real-valued cosine and hyperbolic sine (since $1/2$ has imaginary part $0$), which will restrict $y$ so that $\cosh = 1$, forcing the real solutions to be the only solutions.

If you have shown that the limits are infinity approaching each of these infinitely many singularities, then you have shown that they are not removable.  I'm not convinced you have understood the definition/nature of essential singularities.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'm looking back and I think that they are actually poles of order 1?

Comment: @complexanalysis : I see an exponent in that denominator, so we are looking at the schematic form $1/(0)^2$, which is unlikely to be a pole of order $1$.  For instance, the Laurent series for $f$ at $\pi/6$ is $$\frac{1}{3(z-\pi/6)^2} + \frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}(z-\pi/6)} + \frac{7}{36} + \cdots  \text{.}  $$

Answer (score 1):

$\sin z=\frac{1}{2}$ have infinity many solutions it is periodic function. You are write about the solutions but you need to include all

Comment: Okay, so simply rewrite it to be $\frac{\pi}{6}+2n\pi$ and $\frac{5\pi}{6}+2n\pi$? But are the classifications correct as well?

Comment: For essential points any open disk containing that point is homeomorphic to the whole $\mathbb{C}$ the points are nonremovable because lim is either infinity or -infinity

Comment: Usually we call such points poles.